# What allows us to distinguish a sequence in C major vs A minor?

Tags: key

I understand the difference between the A minor and C major scale. They both incorporate the same notes but begin on different frequencies. Yet, given a sequence of notes from the set {C,D,E,F,G,A,B} , what allows us to tell whether a given sequence in C major and A minor?

Comment: Yeah I agree it is a duplicate, although those answers aren't exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping for something more systematic that explains how to measure / predict the moment at which our expectation of which key it is in shifts.

Comment: Krumhansl's probe tone method for example sorta delves into this but she seems to be the only person I can find doing extensive work on this subject. I was hoping someone else might have ideas related.

Comment: Then why don't you use that question as a starting point for what you want to know? You can always reference an old question and use it to shape the question you want to ask.

Comment: If the last note is A, it's almost definitely in A minor. If the last note is C, it's almost definitely C major. But in neither case is it certain. I'm not sure if there are reliable rules that exist. Once you bring chords into the mix then it gets a lot easier.

Comment: You are making the assumption that "*our* expectation" is a meaningful concept. I don't see any reason why *my* expectation should be the same as *yours*, since we most likely have had a completely different set of musical experiences to form different expectations from. (I don't have a problem considering the chord progression Ab7, Bb9, C  as a cadence in C, for example...)

Comment: The natural minor scale has the same notes as its relative major.  But the harmonic minor scale is also often used, with its sharpened 7th note that strengthens dominant > tonic cadences.  Therefore, although A minor doesn't require G# accidentals, a sprinkling of them strongly indicates that that's where we are!

Answer (score 0):

You should focus your hearing on tonics, dominants, subdominants and accents and the chord progression and the general mood of a major versus minor. When focusing on a cut sequence on notes there is no difference in C major versus A minor by definition of a circle-of-fifth ideas.